# Unable to understand last condition of FizzBuzz in following code

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I can understand how this code produces Fizz , Buzz when divisible by 3 , 5. But confused about how it produces FizzBuzz when divisible by both 3 and 5, because i do not see any if condition which satisfies divisible by both 3 and 5. Please explain.

```js
for (let n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  let output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```

Comment: What would the output be for `n = 15`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both if statement conditions evaluate to true, so it adds both "Fizz" and "Buzz" to "", which results in "FizzBuzz". The += operator is *appending* text to output.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `output += ...;` allows for the variable to be populated with FizzBuzz if/when the iteration is divisible by both 3 AND 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your issue

You don't understand why you get FizzBuzz sometimes ?

For example when n=15 you get it.

Because 15 % 3 = 0 ( 15 = 3*5 ) and 15 % 5 = 0 (15 = 5*3 )

It is the same for 30, 45, 60, 75, 90.

Comment: No, that is not what i meant. i was expecting one more if condition.